# What are cosmere standard gravity and size based on?

Tags: cosmere

*Arcanum Unbounded* talks about the gravity and size of planets in “cosmere standard” gravity and size (e.g. “...its size at around 1.5 cosmere standard...”<sup>1</sup>). I am curious what this is based on.

[This Reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/Cosmere/comments/6up164/comment/dlub20q) says this:

> Cosmere standard is exactly equal to Earth's size and gravitation.

I cannot find a source for this. **Has anything canon said specifically what cosmere standard gravity and size are?**

<sup>1</sup><sub>describing Sel</sub>

Comment: I'm on mobile, so digging up sources and writing a proper answer is a pain right now, but Cosmere standards refers to the planet of Yolen, which itself happens to have to Earth's size and gravity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## They are based on Yolen.

I looked through *Arcanum Unbounded* and found a source for what [Martin Ender said in a comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/215219/what-are-cosmere-standard-gravity-and-size-based-on#comment588028_215219).

Khriss writes:

> It is also very similar to Yolen in size and gravitation.
>   
> <sub>"The Scadrian System"; page 151 of the hardcover first edition.</sub>

---

While I have seen online that it is the size and mass of Earth, I cannot find a source for this, checking [Arcanum](https://wob.coppermind.net/adv_search/?tags=yolen) for Word of Brandon. However, [Brandon said](https://wob.coppermind.net/events/100/#e3377) that Scadrial is the most Earth-like planet, and because it is the exact same size and mass as Yolen it could be presumed that Yolen is pretty close to Earth in that regard.

Comment: @fbstj ? Isn’t the website The Coppermind?

Comment: The Coppermind is more the name for the wiki part of the site.  It's all under the domain 'coppermind.net'; but you can see that the main coppermind.net page doesn't have the Arcanum listed as directly part of it's contents, but has it under "Community" along with the 17th shard forums which don't share the coppermind.net domain (arcanum uses the wob.coppermind.net subdomain anyways); but still have a common origin.

Comment: JMac is correct, [Coppermind](https://coppermind.net/) is the wiki and [Arcanum](https://wob.coppermind.net/) is the quote searcher. it may be moved to a different URL in the future but there's no plans to right now.